# How to resolve Ajax-Zoom error: $.axZm is not a valid object or undefined

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

Good afternoon, I'm trying to run the examples provided by AJAX-ZOOM in local server and in any of the examples always gives the error in console: $.axZm is not valid object or undefined. What could be happening?

Comment: Do you solve yet??

Answer (score -1):

Installing the ioncube solved for me

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you resolved the issue?

Comment: @Fabio Rufino Please add more details to your answer which would help other community member who are looking for similar solutions